# Creating a nested dictionary with data from pre-existing nested dictionary

Tags: python

I need to create a dictionary whose keys are unique course codes and whose values are dictionaries with a single key-value pair describing the sections available for that course code, in alphabetical order, as well as the ID numbers that belong to the specific section, in ascending order.

The data is from a dictionary called student_data that looks like this:

```
student_data[:3]

>>>[{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'UK 60', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GF 24', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'ME 40', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VY 44', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'EN 94', 'section': 'B'}], 
'id': '201001', 'paid': True, 'school': 'SOSE', 'year level': 2}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'EQ 61', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UZ 22', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'KS 36', 'section': 'B'}, 
{'course code': 'VH 63', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'IW 81', 'section': 'C'}], 
'id': '211002', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 1}, 
{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'WE 15', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'ZP 68', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GI 78', 'section': 'A'}, 
{'course code': 'GK 72', 'section': 'C'}, 
{'course code': 'FA 24', 'section': 'D'}, 
{'course code': 'UJ 28', 'section': 'A'}], 
'id': '201003', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 2}]
```

Format of the desired output:

```
{
    course_code: [{
        "section": section_letter,
        "class list": [
           id_number_1,
           id_number_2,
           id_number_3,
        ]
    }
    course_code: [{
        "section": section_letter,
        "class list": [
           id_number_1,
           id_number_2,
           id_number_3,
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I'm really not good with dictionaries in Python because I don't understand it that much yet. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
student_data = [{'enlistment': [{'course code': 'UK 60', 'section': 'A'}, {'course code': 'GF 24', 'section': 'B'}, {'course code': 'ME 40', 'section': 'B'}, {'course code': 'VY 44', 'section': 'D'}, {'course code': 'EN 94', 'section': 'B'}], 'id': '201001', 'paid': True, 'school': 'SOSE', 'year level': 2}, {'enlistment': [{'course code': 'EQ 61', 'section': 'D'}, {'course code': 'UZ 22', 'section': 'B'}, {'course code': 'KS 36', 'section': 'B'}, {'course code': 'VH 63', 'section': 'A'}, {'course code': 'IW 81', 'section': 'C'}], 'id': '211002', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 1}, {'enlistment': [{'course code': 'WE 15', 'section': 'D'}, {'course code': 'ZP 68', 'section': 'A'}, {'course code': 'GI 78', 'section': 'A'}, {'course code': 'GK 72', 'section': 'C'}, {'course code': 'FA 24', 'section': 'D'}, {'course code': 'UJ 28', 'section': 'A'}], 'id': '201003', 'paid': True, 'school': 'JGSOM', 'year level': 2}]
for i in student_data:
   for c in i['enlistment']:
      if c['section'] in d[c['course code']]:
          d[c['course code']][c['section']].append(i['id'])
      else:
          d[c['course code']][c['section']] = [i['id']]

r = {a:[{'section':c, 'class list':d} for c, d in b.items()] for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'UK 60': [{'section': 'A', 'class list': ['201001']}], 'GF 24': [{'section': 'B', 'class list': ['201001']}], 'ME 40': [{'section': 'B', 'class list': ['201001']}], 'VY 44': [{'section': 'D', 'class list': ['201001']}], 'EN 94': [{'section': 'B', 'class list': ['201001']}], 'EQ 61': [{'section': 'D', 'class list': ['211002']}], 'UZ 22': [{'section': 'B', 'class list': ['211002']}], 'KS 36': [{'section': 'B', 'class list': ['211002']}], 'VH 63': [{'section': 'A', 'class list': ['211002']}], 'IW 81': [{'section': 'C', 'class list': ['211002']}], 'WE 15': [{'section': 'D', 'class list': ['201003']}], 'ZP 68': [{'section': 'A', 'class list': ['201003']}], 'GI 78': [{'section': 'A', 'class list': ['201003']}], 'GK 72': [{'section': 'C', 'class list': ['201003']}], 'FA 24': [{'section': 'D', 'class list': ['201003']}], 'UJ 28': [{'section': 'A', 'class list': ['201003']}]}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Is there a way to do this without using non-standard modules? Sorry I've never used defaultdict before so I don't know how it works.